# Configure common log4j xml for multiple sub projects

Tags: log4j

I am trying to use a common log4j xml for subprojects in tomcat. There is a Parent project deployed already and part of the parent project are three other projects. Two projects A and B already exist and the logging works fine. I am adding a new project C and updated the log4j like below. I do see the ProjectC.log file being created (which is happening when tomcat starts up), but there are no Project C related log statements in this file (or any other file). This is my current log4j xml :

```
<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/"
debug="true">

<appender name="rootAppender" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout"> 
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d [%t] %-5p %c - %m%n"/> 
    </layout> 
</appender>

<appender name="ProjectAAppender" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
    <param name="file" value="${catalina.base}/logs/projectA.log"/>
    <param name="Append" value="true"/>
    <param name="MaxFileSize" value="100000KB"/>
    <param name="MaxBackupIndex" value="3"/>
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d [%t] %-5p %c %x - %m%n"/>
    </layout>
</appender>

<appender name="ProjectBAppender" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
    <param name="file" value="${catalina.base}/logs/ProjectB.csv"/>
    <param name="Append" value="true"/>
    <param name="MaxFileSize" value="10000KB"/>
    <param name="MaxBackupIndex" value="3"/>
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout"/>
</appender>

<appender name="ProjectCAppender" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
    <param name="file" value="${catalina.base}/logs/ProjectC.log"/>
    <param name="Append" value="true"/>
    <param name="MaxFileSize" value="10000KB"/>
    <param name="MaxBackupIndex" value="3"/>
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout"/>
</appender>

<logger name="projA" additivity="true">
    <level value ="DEBUG" />
    <appender-ref ref="ProjectAAppender"/>
</logger>
<logger name="projA.Performance" additivity="true">
    <level value ="INFO" />
    <appender-ref ref="ProjectBAppender"/>
</logger>
<logger name="projC" additivity="true">
    <level value ="DEBUG" />
    <appender-ref ref="ProjectCAppender"/>
</logger>   
<root>
    <priority value ="INFO" />
    <appender-ref ref="rootAppender"/>
</root>
```

The way I get my log4j instance is using the slf4j LoggerFactory :

```
LoggerFactory.getLogger(clazz)
```

I have declared dependencies for log4j(1.2.14), slf4j-log4j12(1.4.1) jar files in my pom. 
This setup works fine when I execute Project C independently (when running junit test cases).
How can I make logging work for project C ? Any changes that I should be making to my log4j xml ? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was using the wrong properties file. In the actual log4j.properties file all I had to do was to create a new appender named Project C and added this line instead of registering with the rootCategory :

```
log4j.logger.com.projectC.related.package=DEBUG, ProjectCAppender
```